# Cannot start RabbitMQ Server on CentOS 6.5

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq, chef-infra, yum, sensu

I was about to install Sensu with Chef, but RabbitMQ does not seem to be  working. The service of rabbitmq-server does not start, even though installation of erlang and RabbitMQ was successful.

The error of rabbitMQ says

```
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown
```

and

```
rabbitmq service has already started
```

So I checked the process of rabbitmq with ps command.

```
ps aux |grep rabbitmq
```

for sure one process is running with rabbitmq user

```
/usr/lib64/erlang/erts-6.1/bin/epmd -daemon
```

I killed that process, and restarted the rabbitmq-server service. However failed to start rabbitmq-server and the same log was shown the same thing and the same thing happened.

I once removed the erlang and rabbitmq and reinstalled them, but the result was same.

The followings are the detail.

Server

```
OS: CentOS 6.5

Related installed packages
erlang.x86_64       17.1-1.1.el6
rabbitmq-server.noarch      3.1.5-1.el6
```

Original log

```
# /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server status


Status of node rabbit@localhost ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@localhost: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

nodes in question: [rabbit@localhost]

hosts, their running nodes and ports:
- localhost: [{rabbitmqctl23036,37270}]

current node details:
- node name: rabbitmqctl23036@localhost
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- cookie hash: Tghu0ucbQ4pq3Sc0JJBbAg==



# tail /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit\@localhost.log



=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
Starting RabbitMQ 3.1.5 on Erlang 17
Copyright (C) 2007-2013 GoPivotal, Inc.
Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
node           : rabbit@localhost
home dir       : /var/lib/rabbitmq
cookie hash    : 9qNy1Q7BP12PVVcbSnZwRw==
log            : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
sasl log       : /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
database dir   : /var/lib/rabbitmq/mnesia/rabbit@localhost

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
Limiting to approx 924 file handles (829 sockets)

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
Memory limit set to 802MB of 2006MB total.

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
Disk free limit set to 1000MB

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
msg_store_transient: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
msg_store_persistent: using rabbit_msg_store_ets_index to provide index

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
started TCP Listener on [::]:5672

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:15 ===
Error description:
   {case_clause,{error,{already_started,<0.193.0>}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log

Stack trace:
   [{rabbit_networking,start_listener0,4,[]},
    {rabbit_networking,'-start_listener/4-lc$^0/1-0-',4,[]},
    {rabbit_networking,start_listener,4,[]},
    {rabbit_networking,'-boot_ssl/0-lc$^0/1-0-',1,[]},
    {rabbit_networking,boot_ssl,0,[]},
    {rabbit_networking,boot,0,[]},
    {rabbit,'-run_boot_step/1-lc$^1/1-1-',1,[]},
    {rabbit,run_boot_step,1,[]}]


=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:16 ===
stopped TCP Listener on [::]:5672

=INFO REPORT==== 6-Aug-2014::14:59:16 ===
Error description:
   {could_not_start,rabbit,
       {bad_return,
           {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
            {'EXIT',
                {rabbit,failure_during_boot,
                    {case_clause,{error,{already_started,<0.193.0>}}}}}}}}

Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@localhost-sasl.log
```

Comment: The port 5672 is already taken? Maybe you can use lsof to check?

Comment: are you using the same user to start rabbitmq and to contact it later? Erlang programs must use the same `.erlang.cookie` file in order to be able to contact each other

Comment: In my case I had `ssl_listeners` configured in `rabbitmq.config` but not `tcp_listeners`; when I added a `tcp_listeners` to the config (with a different port), the service started to work again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the port that RabbitMQ (`5672` to be exact) is using is already taken. Or in your case it might be still taken. If you kill application that opened socket on some port, you are not giving it time to close this connection properly.  System will eventualy notice this and free the resource, but it might take some time. So what you could do is wait a little, or change [RabbitMQ configuration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/configure.html).

Hope this will help with some of your problems.